# How can I check if inside a JTable is already an equal row than the row I want to add?

Tags: java, swing

I already have a solution, but I want a more professional solution. Here it is:

```
private boolean modelContains(Object[] product, DefaultTableModel model) {
    boolean contains = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        if(product[1].equals(model.getValueAt(i, 1))) {
            System.out.println(product);
            contains = true;
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps maintain a `Map` or `List` of identifiers, which would be quicker to search.  Have a custom `TableModel` which can perform the check and reject any duplicates

Comment: Could you show me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: `contains` is not really needed. Simply `return true` in side the `if`  or `return false` at the end.  It will shorten the evaluation time.

Comment: Do you want "check if inside a JTable is already an equal row than the row I want to add" to prevent duplicationor for other purpose ?

Comment: Why are you passing in an Array if you only check one item of the Array? And why would that value be at index 1. Instead, just pass in the Object you want to search for.

Comment: Yes, I want to check it to prevent duplication

Comment: I'm using an array because my method retrieves an object from database (using hibernate) as an Array (one location per field, e.g. If the object i've serialized has fields String name, Integer index and Double payment it retrieves like Object[0] = name; Object[1] = index and Object[2] = payment).